# 2 players. Can I play the draw 2 after a draw 4 if it was the last card to the previous player?

Tags: uno

[image: can I play the draw 2?]

If the first player has their last card as a draw 4 wild card and says uno out,can the next player ask for a color to possibly counter with a draw 2 of the corresponding color said by the first player?

Comment: Can you be more specific,I don't understand your answer.

Comment: The game is over as soon as a player plays their last card so nothing can be done in response.